# Convert a double to a SQL-friendly string on Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My open-source Android application uses this in an SQL query:

```
String.format("%f", someDoubleValue);
```

Unfortunately, in some languages the coma is "," instead of "." and the SQL engine does not like it.

What is the best way to convert a double to a SQL-friendly string on Android?

Comment: Have you considered using query parameters?

Comment: Mark, do you mean something like query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol=?", someDoubleValue); ? I will try

Comment: Mark, Android does not have query parameters

Comment: Isn't the Java function Double.toString(someDoubleValues) working, or am I misunderstanding you question?

Comment: It might be as simple as that! I will try as soon as I can.

Comment: I am afraid it is not going to work because when a double it is long enough the toString() method it is going to represent it with an exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wild guess:

```
Locale nullLocale = null;
String.format(nullLocale, "%f", someDoubleValue);
```

I don't have any means to test it now, unfortunately.

Comment: It works, confirmed by two users. I am still open to any better solution. If there is a "standard" or "official" way to deal with this, I would prefer it.